# puppeteer page.select with multiple class doesn't seem to work

Tags: puppeteer

I'm new to puppeeteer I have this html https://jsitor.com/c0rM-YohL

```
<input type="input" class="test-element Input">
<select class="test-element Dropdown">
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
</select>
```

I tried with this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/puppeteer-ide/ilehdekjacappgghkgmmlbhgbnlkgoid?hl=en-US

```
await page.type(".test-element .Input", "new-test-app");
await page.select(".test-element .Dropdown", "option1");
```

but it doesn't work with

```
await page.goto('https://jsitor.com/c0rM-YohL', {
   waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
});

await page.type(".test-element.Input", "new-test-app");
await page.select(".test-element.Dropdown", "option1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the extra space from the selectors:

```
await page.type(".test-element.Input", "new-test-app");
await page.select(".test-element.Dropdown", "option1");
```

**EDIT:**

it's within an iframe, so you need to get iframe first:

```
const iframeSelector = '.iframe-container iframe';

await page.waitForSelector(iframeSelector, {
    visible: true
});

const frameHandle = await page.$(iframeSelector);
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();

await frame.type(".test-element.Input", "new-test-app");
let selected = await frame.select(".test-element.Dropdown", "test2");
console.log('selected', selected);
```

Comment: I can't make it work see my update with https://jsitor.com/c0rM-YohL
 (I'm using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/puppeteer-ide/ilehdekjacappgghkgmmlbhgbnlkgoid?hl=en-US)

Comment: @user310291 it's within an iframe. check the updated code

Comment: wow great it works, I did see a class iframe but missed the real iframe :)

Comment: I thought it woud be simple next to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896797/puppeteer-cannot-select-attribute-tabindex can you help again thanks

Answer (score 0):

option1 is an element inside the `<select>` object. You need to type your text, click on the dropdown, and only then click on the relevant option.

Comment: I don't understand can you give code ?