# Puppeteer cannot select attribute tabindex

Tags: css-selectors, puppeteer

Subsequent to [puppeteer page.select with multiple class doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881004/puppeteer-page-select-with-multiple-class-doesnt-seem-to-work) I now want to select the second dropdown by tabindex but it doesn't work

```js
      await page.goto('https://jsitor.com/c0rM-YohL', {
         waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
      });

      const iframeSelector = '.iframe-container iframe';

      await page.waitForSelector(iframeSelector, {
          visible: true
      });

      const frameHandle = await page.$(iframeSelector);
      const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();

      await frame.type(".test-element.Input", "test input");
      let selected = await frame.select(".test-element.Dropdown [tabindex='2']", "test4");
      console.log('selected', selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure not to put a space between the [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) and the [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

- `".test-element.Dropdown [tabindex='2']"` ❌
- `".test-element.Dropdown[tabindex='2']"` ✔️

like this:

```js
let selected = await frame.select(".test-element.Dropdown[tabindex='2']", 'test4')
```

it will result:

```
selected [ 'test4' ]
```

*Note:* you can test CSS selectors yourself in Chrome DevTools Console by typing the selector inside `$()`. E.g. If you click within the iframe(!) and type `$(".test-element.Dropdown [tabindex='2']")` it will return `null` while `$(".test-element.Dropdown[tabindex='2']")` returns `select.test-element.Dropdown`.